# Creating event for ASP.NET Server Control in VS from Source View

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to create Event (for example Button click event) from Source View? I mean without going to design view ?

Comment: In short, the answer is yes, but to get an appropriate answer, we'll need to know what language you are coding in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you create your method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And in your markup (not the design view), you add your button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

That should be it.

Comment: In VB.net, you can use the 'handles' syntax at the end of a method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can add an event handler dynamically in Codebehind f.e.(VB.Net):

```
AddHandler Me.Button1.Click, AddressOf Me.Button1_Click
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an eventhandler and assign a method to it.

```
ButtonId.click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```